# How can I get auto-completion in bash for file-names with spaces, too?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, terminal

I'm pretty new to this whole Terminal business and had things working nicely on my old laptop with Snow Leopard installed.

New laptop with Snow Leopard works differently, however. When using the terminal, when trying to get auto-completion to work, it won't auto-complete for directory names with spaces in them. I know I can type it in manually and escape that space, but I'd love to get auto-complete to work.

What can I do here?

Comment: That's odd, I've just tried it and it's fine on my Snow Leopard system. Can't even think how you'd disable just that functionality. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will help out here.

Comment: Is this happening for all directory names on all commands, or just on cd? I ask because directory name completion is internal, so it seems like there'd have to be a buggy version of bash for it to break. (If it's just cd... do you have CDPATH set? That'd make it use the special cd completion in the extended bash completion script, which might be more likely to be buggy, I suppose...)

Comment: It looks like it is for all directories, and only for the cd... Not sure what you mean by CDPath, so I'll google it. Interestingly enough, if I type sudo cd The[tab] it will auto-complete..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know, I'd swear this used to work and just seemed to stop working recently (last few months). Don't know that any OS X updates updated bash, but whatever.

Anyway, putting "complete -o nospace -d cd" into .bashrc (or whatever rc file you're using) seems to give the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which might be more straightforward.
You have to the *escape character*  \ followed by a space

e.g.

```
ls Xcode\ 5.0<tab>
```

Then "Xcode 5.0" would be considered as a whole string rather than two separate parameters.